# AX 2012 Auto-fill part of Account structure

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

i want to know if it is possible to develop following feature.
I have a config of this account strucure:

[image: account structure]

This is what the journal creation looks for the user:
[image]

Now i want to develop, if the Lookup return only one opportunity, that the system choose this by default.
For the user would mean this, that he choose an agreement and skipped the steps where he choose the BusModel, Vessel, Owner and only has to choose the VAC.
Anybody an idea?
BG James

Comment: Did you take a look at [The Dynamics AX2012 Segmented Entry Control for Developers – Introduction](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tlefor/2013/08/30/the-dynamics-ax2012-segmented-entry-control-for-developers-introduction/)? Seems that class `LedgerDimensionAccountController` is a good place to start.

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i develop another feature, that fits for me.

In the class LedgerDimensionAccountController in the method segmentValueChanged, i develop something like this:

```
else if (strLen(newValue) > 0)
    {
        // First assume string is a record value
        dimAttributeValue = LedgerDimensionAccountController::getDimensionAttributeValueServer(dimAttributeId, newValue);
        //Custom Code
        try{
            agrdimAttr = dimensionAttribute::findByName("Agreement");
            if(dimAttributeId == agrdimAttr.RecId){
                busmodel = subStr(newValue, 12, 2);
                busModeldimAttr = dimensionAttribute::findByName("BusModel");
                dimAttributeValue2 = LedgerDimensionAccountController::getDimensionAttributeValueServer(busModeldimAttr.RecId, busmodel);
                vessel = subStr(newValue,1,4);
                vesdimAttr = dimensionAttribute::findByName("Vessel");
                dimAttributeValue3 = LedgerDimensionAccountController::getDimensionAttributeValueServer(vesdimAttr.RecId, vessel);
                automatic =true;
            }else{
                automatic =false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception::Error)
        {
            automatic = false;
            info("Error");
        }
        //CustomCode
```

and at the end of the method

```
this.setValue(segmentIndex, dimAttributeValue, newValue);
        if(automatic){
            segmentIndex++;
            this.setValue(segmentIndex, dimAttributeValue2, busmodel);
            segmentIndex++;
            this.setValue(segmentIndex, dimAttributeValue3, vessel);
        }
```

IN the first step, the dimensionAttribute from BusinessModel and Vessel will be detected. Then we get the DimensionAttributeValue an set it in the second Code section.

BG James